# Distributed transaction reconciliation architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices

There is a minor difference between Saga pattern https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html and my use case below. Saga pattern is about distributed transaction when an event is happening vs my use case below is a reconciliation pattern after events have all happened.

We have a large ecosystem of microservices (300+) in a division (2000+ employees). All our services loosely follow a message driven architecture. For example in an ecommerce world we have a System A which sends a message `Customer X placed an order for item Y for $4.50. Order Id is 123`. There is then a System B which may be a payment service which receives this message and actually debits the Customer's payment method (paypal/debit card etc) for $4.50 which then sends a message that `Payment was received from Customer X for item Y for $4.50`. This will be received by two systems a warehouse system which will start shipping the order and perhaps a compliance system which will ensure this gets reported correctly.

Given an order id such as `123` above I am designing a reconciliation system where all the events that are expected to occur such as OrderPlaced, PaymentReceived, ItemShipped, ComplianceCheckDone have actually happened. It appears an Order follows a typical workflow and each microservice sends updates as and when parts of it are triggered.

There are multiple ways to solve this however I am looking for existing architecture best practices, blue prints, patterns (frameworks?) to solve this problem. Assume no constraint on languages, systems, compilers etc.

Comment: Have you looked at event sourcing? What is the goal of this new system?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are describing somewhat fits with [distributed tracing](https://microservices.io/patterns/observability/distributed-tracing.html) or [observability](https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-observability) - the main idea being that you attach a randomly generated correlation ID to the original request that is attached to all resulting events, allowing you to reconcile the process through the system.